# How to locate which column a value came from

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have used `PortReturns["Highest_Returns"] = PortReturns.max(axis=1)` to note which of the 10 stocks have the highest return within a given day.
Now I am trying to identify which column the values within the Highest_Returns came from,with the column label inputted under the Highest_Returns_Ticker column.

```
            Date  Returns_Apple  ... Returns_UL Highest_Returns  Highest_Returns_Ticker

0     2013-02-25            NaN  ...       NaN             NaN                   Input
1     2013-02-26       0.013934  ... -0.005093        0.013934                   Input
2     2013-02-27      -0.009800  ...  0.017405        0.024307                   Input
3     2013-02-28      -0.007130  ...  0.002516        0.004762                   Input
4     2013-03-01      -0.024762  ...  0.005019        0.029093                   Input
...          ...            ...  ...       ...             ...                     ...
2514  2023-02-17      -0.007547  ...  0.007081        0.020877                   Input
2515  2023-02-21      -0.026680  ...  0.005273        0.006078                   Input
2516  2023-02-22       0.002896  ... -0.003692        0.004793                   Input
2517  2023-02-23       0.003291  ... -0.002420        0.140214                   Input
2518  2023-02-24      -0.018005  ... -0.008284        0.002674                   Input
\[2519 rows x 12 columns\]
```

So what I would like to see is

```
            Date  Returns_Apple  ... Returns_UL Highest_Returns  Highest_Returns_Ticker

0     2013-02-25            NaN  ...       NaN             NaN                      NaN
1     2013-02-26       0.013934  ... -0.005093        0.013934            Returns_Apple
2     2013-02-27      -0.009800  ...  0.017405        0.024307            Returns_NVDA
3     2013-02-28      -0.007130  ...  0.002516        0.004762            Returns_UL
4     2013-03-01      -0.024762  ...  0.005019        0.029093            Returns_WLMT
...          ...            ...  ...       ...             ...                     ...
2514  2023-02-17      -0.007547  ...  0.007081        0.020877                     Etc
2515  2023-02-21      -0.026680  ...  0.005273        0.006078                     Etc
2516  2023-02-22       0.002896  ... -0.003692        0.004793                     Etc
2517  2023-02-23       0.003291  ... -0.002420        0.140214                     Etc
2518  2023-02-24      -0.018005  ... -0.008284        0.002674                     Etc
\[2519 rows x 12 columns\]
```

Im assuming that you have to create a function that matches the Highest_Returns values with  one of the 10 columns, which you then return the column label.

I am a new to python so any sort of help or explanation will be greatly appreciated

Comment: try `PortReturns.idxmax(1)`

Comment: I get this "TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this type". It seems like I may need to change the column type

Comment: perhaps you have non numeric columns in your dataframe

Comment: I would have thought so too, but I didn't get the same error when using  .max for Highest_Returns

Comment: well did you check?

Comment: Other than the date column which is an object, the rest of the columns are labelled floats64. Maybe I should change the date column into a numeric?Ill try it

Comment: Ok, it seemed to have worked out now. As the date column was causing the error I just excluded it by using `PortReturns.loc[: ,PortReturns.columns!='Date'].idxmax(1)`. I can now see the labels under the column. I appreciate the help, thanks.